# Ubuntu 21.04 автоматически отключает USB 3.0 порт

Tags: linux, ubuntu, flash, usb

Недавно обновился на Ubuntu 21.04 и столкнулся с проблемой. Время от времени (чаще всего при отключенном питании ноутбука) система сама отключает порт USB 3.0. При этом порт 2.0 работает стабильно. Порт включается автоматически после простоя в режиме сна (пару раз включался сам). При этом флешку он видит и открывает, а мышь, клавиатуру и другие устройства не видит, но питание по порту идет. Думаю, что что-то с настройками электропитания. Как решить данную проблему, как я могу выключить автоотключение порта?

Когда ноутбук зарядился до 100%, мышь включилась сама.

Answer (score 6):

**Может ли быть так, что инструменты режима ноутбука вызывают это? Если это так, попробуйте следующее:**

Получить идентификатор USB вашей мыши / клавиатуры:

```
lsusb
```

Это вернет список, в том числе ID xxxx:xxxx для вашей мыши / клавиатуры.

Теперь нам необходимо редактировать оригинал `usb-autosuspend.conf`:

```
sudo gedit /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf
```

Там будет запись под названием `AUTOSUSPEND_USBID_BLACKLIST=''`, изменить это на `AUTOSUSPEND_USBID_BLACKLIST='xxxx:xxxx'`.

Это должно остановить вашу мышь / клавиатуру USB от приостановки. Теперь вам нужно либо перезагрузить компьютер, либо перезапустить режим ноутбука, используя:

```
sudo service laptop-mode restart
```

Данное решение сработало на моём ноутбуке :)

Comment: /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf - такого пути не существует. upd: установил утилиту, путь нашелся.

Comment: @khlebovsky данное решение вам помогло? Если помогло пожалуйста сделайте отметку "Автор вопроса принял ответ"